# How to temporarily hide GADBannerView in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, admob

I am using Admob to show ads in my ios application.
Now I have 5 views that scrolls horizontally, like paging.
I want to show ad when user is on first page and want to unhide when user scrolls to another pages.

I am successfully able to load the advertisement. But not able to hide them when the page scrolles.

my code to show add

```
_bannerView_ = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait];
[_bannerView_ setFrame:CGRectMake(_bannerView_.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.size.height-_bannerView_.frame.size.height, _bannerView_.frame.size.width, _bannerView_.frame.size.height)];

_bannerView_.adUnitID = MY_BANNER_UNIT_ID;


_bannerView_.rootViewController = self;



[_bannerView_ loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];

[self.view addSubview:_bannerView_];
```

when user scrolls

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
CGFloat pageWidth = self.scrll_restaurant_detail.frame.size.width;
NSInteger page = (NSInteger)floor((self.scrll_restaurant_detail.contentOffset.x * 2.0f + pageWidth) / (pageWidth * 2.0f));
if(page==0){
[_bannerView_ setHidden:FALSE];
}else{
[_bannerView_ setHidden:TRUE];
}
}
```

but its not hiding my Bannerview.

Help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove it from superview and then again add it. You can remove it by using below code snippets

```
[_bannerView_ removeFromSuperView];
```

Comment: i used this technique most often :)

Answer (score 1):

Set your banner attribute hidden to YES. It will do the trick!

```
_bannerView_.hidden
```